# Converting string from CSV to date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, csv, date, datetime

I am trying to import a CSV file that has a datetime string in this format '43924.84611'.  I am at a loss as to how to convert this into a readable datetime string.

Have tried:

```
STR_TO_DATE()
CAST()
CONVERT()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Tom

Comment: What date is that?

Comment: which tool you use to import

Answer (score 0):

Please try

select from_unixtime(round('43924.84611')) as datetime;

Result:

"1970-01-01 12:12:05"

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helped with finding the solution.

Comment: @Tominbaltimore Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> datetime string in this format '43924.84611'.

Looks like Excel-encoded `'2020-04-03 20:18:24'`.

If so then

> ```
> SET @val := 43924.84611;
> ```

> ```
> select from_unixtime((@val - 25569)*86400)
> ```
>
> ```
> | from_unixtime((@val - 25569)*86400) |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 2020-04-03 21:18:23.904000          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d156fe56b7b206b7a485886d7056360)*

Comment: Bing, bing, bing, we have a winner.  That is it.  Thank you so much.